# How to restrict access to DSNs defined in the Coldfusion administrator?

Tags: coldfusion, dsn

Coldfusion provides the Coldfusion Administrator as a way to define Data Source Names (DSNs) that we can use to connect to various databases. My question is this - Say I define the following DSNs in the administrator:

- DSN1
- DSN2
- DSN3 etc.

We have a shared server situation and do not want all the programmers who are using the server to have access to all of the above DSNs (I believe by default, if they knew the DSN name, they could simply use it). So for example, we may want programmer X to be able to use DSN1 but not DSN2 and DSN3.

Is there a way to prevent/restrict access to DSNs in a situation like the above?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you need to enable security sandboxes and restrict each site to only have access to its own DSN's

Comment: Cheers snake. For anyone that is looking for additional information, here is the relevant documentation page: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Security_4.html